# Python Selenium will not print the number inside <td>

Tags: python, selenium

For some reason, I cannot print the .text (7) with Python selenium:

I tried the XPATH and the Full XPATH

```
license_available_1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="overlayBlack"]/app-root/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/app-pak-tokens/div/div/div/div[2]/p-table/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/span').text
print(license_available_1)
```

Here is the html code:

```
<td _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="" class="no-padding valignMiddle" style="width:69px;"><span _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="" class="wrapColData text-right">7</span></td>
```

When I try it with chrome under windows, it works, but when using headless chrome under linux, it fails to print the number (7) with no error message.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As you mentioned it works without --headless. Try setting the headless to fullscreen using ```driver.maximize_window()```. As it is headless you might need to pass the desired resolution. If the element is present but out of screen, the value won't be returned. You may also try an action on the element. For example scroll to it first using: ```driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", el)``` then retrieve the value

Comment: @NicLaforge Thank you for your response. I maximized the window right before running the command, and last 2 columns containing the numbers gets cut off for some reason. I also tried to refresh the page before running the command. I took a screenshot right before running the command (updated the original post with the screenshot)

Comment: As suspect the ```driver.maximize_window()``` won't work under headless. Try adding the resolution you want to run your test as follow ```opts.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
opts.add_argument("--headless")```. You can confirm it was set properly by printing ```print(driver.get_window_rect())```